# MMS support for Android devices

Tags: android, mms

Is there any version specification for MMS in Android?
Which Android devices have MMS support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android SDK Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html) mentions issues of "unable to send MMS between *emulators* at 1.0", and [Android 1.5 Platform Highlight](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.5-highlights.html) says "UI polish for MMS". I believe MMS is always supported by Android, at least since 1.5, i.e. almost [all Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) on the market.